# What could cause python to shut down without any error?

Tags: python, debugging

I have a problem I never experienced before : A python program fails "silently" : I have no Exception, no error, no backtrace. When I try to breakpoint, a short message says python is shutting down.

The app is quite complex (I can't provide minimum failing program) with many asynchronous generators (graph flow pipeline), and use some memory (~3GB) but nothing the computer should not have been able to handle...

How would you address such bugs, and what could cause it ?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no bottleneck, As the OS sometimes kill the process and a kill process is shown at the last.

Comment: Has the program try blocks with an `except:` line and no exception(s) specified in front?